# Lead Lookup in a simple Screen Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, lookup, leads, visual-flows

I'm totally new to Flows. I'm trying to design a simple screen flow, that allows me to select a Lead and then delete it, along with associated Custom Object records in one go.

As of now, I need to delete the custom object records first and then the lead, in order to prevent orphaned records being left behind.

As a simple first step, I'm trying to use a lookup component to search for Leads. What I'm unsure of is to what to enter in the highlighted fields.
[image]

All searches I've done seem to indicate that the lookup object does the lookup from an associated object. What I need is a simple Lead search.

How do I go about that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

Object API name: API Name of Child Object 
Field API Name: The Lookup Field(Lead) API Name on Child Object

Comment: Hi - thank you. I was able to play around and figure it out based on your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Field API Name of "Id", instead use "MasterRecordId". That fixed the problem for me!

[image: Lead Lookup Settings]